# QGIS 2.0 How can i get a precisely Rendering time?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, rendering

I work with QGIS 2.0.1.

I have a large number of raster data files and i selected different methods to represent them.

1. Method: Import all raster data as individual files
2. Method: Generate a single file with the help of the rastertool "Merge"
3. Method: Generate a virtual raster (catalog)

I would like to know if it is possible to get the exact Rendering time? For example how long qgis needs to render the map if you zoom in.

This would be very helpful to compare the rendering time between the three methods.
I know which method is faster but a time value would be important for me.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You can enable rendering logging under `Settings -> Options -> Rendering`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also just start your favourite system monitor and look at how long it takes to render your map. That also gives you information of which hardware is your bottleneck. In my example it took about 10 seconds to render the map before the CPU went back to idling. I would even say it is better than just the time value because your data gives you "time - CPU-load". Integrating over that function is a better measure than just the overall time.

[image]